# Registered for an account with same email, lost all previous data (2)

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Previous unregistered id: 608793
Registered, lost privileges, etc... w/ new account: 171794

merge please? :)

Comment: Your current ID is 1024381.  The second you listed is for MSO, not SO.

Comment: Account 171794 is your account id here on meta. Did you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/users/1024381/ account?

Answer (score 1):

I merged these two SO accounts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024381/
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/608793/

as both had the same email address.